# Is MVP pattern best way for every winforms app?

Tags: winforms, client, design-patterns, mvp, smartclient

i would like develop application about storing some information about books, i would like use MVP pattern - but i have some doubts if this pattern is always best practise for developing small/mid winform apps or maybe is not necessary?

ps. I would like use Smart Client Factory from Microsoft, is there any framework for MVP in winforms?

thanks in advance for all ideas

Comment: Have a look at this question as to whether its a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144032/is-mvc-mvp-with-winforms-an-anti-pattern

Comment: MVP is a really easy pattern to implement yourself.  I'm sure there are frameworks but you don't need one.  It is the ideal pattern to use with Windows Forms.  I ran into questions about architectures a lot so I wrote a post about it and it should provide more detail for you. MVVM vs MVP vs MVC: The differences explained. http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one pattern is best for every app. For more interaction applications, I prefer the MVVM pattern. MVVM is usually reserved for WPF and Silverlight, but it's possible to use MVVM in Windows Forms with the [Update Controls](http://updatecontrols.net/cs/winforms.shtml) framework.